# Google Tag Manager Mobile App - Can't access screen names

Tags: firebase, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

**Goal**

Use screen name as variable in GTM for Mobile Apps

Screen_name is tracked as parameter in built-in event screen_view

**Problem**

I can't create variable to access values from parameter screen_name.

In BigQuery this parameter is reported as firebase_screen

**What I have tried**

I have tried to access value with several parameter naming:

```
screen_name
firebase_screen
firebase_screen_name
screenName
firebaseScreen
firebaseScreenName
```

And none of these work.

Any ideas? I assume this is a bug.

Workaround is to log a custom parameter screen_name, but this is not ideal because developers needs to be involved.